# Separating a string into numbers and letters in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, split

I started learning python two days ago. Today I built a web scraping script which pulls data from yahoo finance and puts it in a csv file. The problem I have is that some values are string because yahoo finance displays them as such.

For example: Revenue: 806.43M

When I copy them into the csv I cant use them for calculation so I was wondering if it is possible to separate the "806.43" and "M" while still keeping both to see the unit of the number and put them in two different columns.

for the excel writing I use this command:

```
f.write(revenue + "," + revenue_value + "\n")
```

where:

```
print(revenue)
Revenue (ttm)
print(revenue_value)
806.43M
```

so in the end I should be able to use a command which looks something like this

```
f.write(revenue + "," + revenue_value + "," + revenue_unit + "\n")
```

where revenue_value is 806.43 and revenue_unit is M

Hope someone could help with the problem.

Comment: If you’re looking for a way to get that data without scraping, try this package:  [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Can get revenue (as well as all income statement data) with the following:  `Ticker(‘aapl’).income_statement()`.  Just replace ‘aapl’ with your ticker or list of tickers.  Result is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I just checked it out, thats actually very cool and easy to use thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to parse the number as string and convert it to a float based on the unit in the end of the string.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
def parse_number(number_str) -> float:
    mapping = {
        "K": 1000,
        "M": 1000000,
        "B": 1000000000
    }

    unit = number_str[-1]
    number_float = float(number_str[:-1])

    return number_float * mapping[unit]
```

And here's an example:

```
my_number = "806.43M"
print(parse_number(my_number))
>>> 806430000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

[Here's](https://regex101.com/) a pretty good online tool to let you practice using Python-specific standards.

```
import re

sample = "Revenue (ttm): 806.43M"

# Note: the `(?P<name here>)` section is a named group. That way we can identify what we want to capture.
financials_pattern = r'''
    (?P<category>.+?):?\s+?     # Capture everything up until the colon
    (?P<value>[\d\.]+)          # Capture only numeric values and decimal points
    (?P<unit>[\w]*)?            # Capture a trailing unit type (M, MM, etc.)
'''

# Flags:
#     re.I -> Ignore character case (upper vs lower)
#     re.X -> Allows for 'verbose' pattern construction, as seen above
res = re.search(financials_pattern, sample, flags = re.I | re.X)
```

Print our dictionary of values:

```
res.groupdict()
```

Output:

```
{'category': 'Revenue (ttm)',
'value': '806.43',
'unit': 'M'}
```

We can also use .groups() to list results in a tuple.

```
res.groups()
```

Output:

```
('Revenue (ttm)', '806.43', 'M')
```

In this case, we'll immediately unpack those results into your variable names.

```
revenue = None # If this is None after trying to set it, don't print anything.

revenue, revenue_value, revenue_unit = res.groups()
```

We'll use fancy f-strings to print out both your `f.write()` call along with the results we've captured.

```
if revenue:
    print(f'f.write(revenue + "," + revenue_value + "," + revenue_unit + "\\n")\n')
    print(f'f.write("{revenue}" + "," + "{revenue_value}" + "," + "{revenue_unit}" + "\\n")')
```

Output:

```
f.write(revenue + "," + revenue_value + "," + revenue_unit + "\n")

f.write("Revenue (ttm)" + "," + "806.43" + "," + "M" + "\n")
```

Comment: thanks, for the detailed response. I will definitely look into and also thanks a lot for the practice tool

Comment: No prob! I actually have a Yahoo! Finance web scraping sampler in one of my repos (link is at the end of this comment). Around line number 199 you can see how a portfolio of data is made from all the functions and variables.  (I should probably add more commentary down the line.)  Link -> https://github.com/MarkMoretto/finance/blob/master/data/y_finance.py

Comment: A Jupyter Notebook is here: https://github.com/MarkMoretto/finance/blob/master/risk/VaR_Three_Equity_Portfolio.ipynb

Comment: Thank you so much, haha yeah I think I need to get more knowledge to fully understand the code and what it does where but helpful anyways!